# Registering an address with userid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to register the addresses with the userid. I manage to add an address per user. But my problem  is that a user can have more address.

Model

```
export class Adresse {
    constructor(public prenom: string, 
                public nom: string,
                public adresse: string,
                public commune: string,
                public numeroF: string,
                public numeroL: string){}
}
```

service adresse

```
saveAdresse(){
    firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set(this.adresse);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new address child node under the user's node each time you call `saveAdresse`, you need to call `push` instead of `set`:

```
saveAdresse(){
  firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).push(this.adresse);
}
```

Each time you call `push` Firebase generates a new child node with a unique ID.

---

If you later want to show all addresses for a specific user, you can do so with:

```
let userAddresses = firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
userAddresses.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((addressSnapshot) => {
    console.log(addressSnapshot.key); // shows the auto-generated ID for each address
    console.log(addressSnapshot.val()); // shows the address value
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening, thank you. I can recover from the console but I can not see the content on the address page. I have this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSWlL.jpg)

adresse.page.ts

```
adresse = {} as Adresse;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    let useradresse = firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    useradresse.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((addressSnapshot) => {
        console.log (addressSnapshot.val()); // shows the address value 
        this.adresse = addressSnapshot.val();
      })
    })

  }
```

Page html

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let adress of adresse; let i = index" (click)="onViewAdresse(i)">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="9" >
                        <!--<ion-col size="9" (click)="goTo(adress)">-->
                    <div><b>{{adress.prenom}} {{adress.nom}} </b></div>
                    <div>{{adress.commune}}</div>
                    <div>{{adress.numeroF}}</div>

                </ion-col>
                <ion-col size="3">
                    <div class="color-edit"><b>Modifier</b></div>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```